# Evaluation order with std::tie() and assignment

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Is the following valid?

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<T, T> foo(T one, T two) { ... }

std::tie(one, two) = foo(std::move(one), std::move(two));
```

(Assuming that the classes involved handle assigning to a moved-from object in a valid manner).

---

From reading the updated [evaluation order proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r1.pdf), my assumption was that this was fixed, but I can't find an exact reference in the standard that verifies this. Could someone help provide that?

Comment: You may want to pick a different function name so that it is clear at a glance that this has nothing to do with [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Comment: @Brian Good point, updated the question.

Comment: Both LHS and RHS evaluations are sequenced-before the assignment so there shouldn't be anything.

Comment: That link to the proposed changes was fascinating, thanks for that.  Any indication that it was ever accepted?

Comment: @MarkRansom I couldn't find the list of accepted proposal for C++17 but points 14-21 look like they were related to the linked proposal here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 2):

The relevant section from the standard can be found in [[expr.ass]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#1) and it has

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. The right operand is sequenced before the left operand. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation.

So, according to this, `foo(std::move(one), std::move(two));` will be evaluated first, leaving `one` and `two` as moved from objects once `std::tie(one, two)` is evaluated.  `tie` create references, so there is no accessing the moved from objects there.  Then the assignment actually happens meaning `one` and `two` get assigned to via `std::tuple::operator =` and get whatever value `foo` returns.  This is legal and well defined.

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid, regardless of C++17 changes to evaluation order of `=`.

Since LHS doesn't read from `one`, `two`, but merely takes their addresses, it being unsequenced (pre-C++17) relative to the RHS doesn't cause UB.